# Is there an option to reduce the size of the Note Tool icons? They are huge in 2023

Tags: adobe-photoshop

It seems like somewhere between PS 2021 and 2023 the "sticky" notes icons left by the Notes Tool are much larger, and are obscuring parts of the image, especially when zoomed out. Every once in a while, it makes a "normal" smaller size note. This must be some sort of bug or bad implementation of a preference size for the notes. Is there a way to set the icon/note size?

EDIT : new Notes (left) vs. old Notes (right).
[image]

Comment: Hey welcome to GDSE, Can you include a screenshot, so it is more clear if this is a bug or the default.

Comment: And no, I'm pretty sure there is no way apart from building an extension script to change this.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't remember if these look any different from the last version TBH, and I can't seem to reproduce the problem you mention of different sized icons. If the sticky note icons are obscuring something, perhaps just turn them off. Go to *View > Show*, and uncheck *Notes*. Repeat to turn them back on. If it's a bug, these are generally off-topic here. Something Adobe would need to fix.

Comment: You're correct. The notes got much larger and it's super annoying. If programming time was going to be spent designing new note icons, it would have been put to better use creating a note size preference.